# How to write a starter script to start my backend and frontend?

Tags: python, bash, shell, flask, npm

I running python flask as my backend and react as my frontend. Every time I start my app, I have to run `export FLASK_APP=app` and then `flask start` in terminal 1 and `npm start` in terminal 2. How do I write a single script that starts both processes? 
Here is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
flask run > /dev/null
npm start --prefix ~/app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
flask run > /dev/null & pids=$!
npm start --prefix ~/app & pids+=" $!"

trap "kill $pids" SIGTERM SIGINT
for pid in $pids; do
    wait $pid
done
```

This script starts both flask and npm in background, and stores their PIDs. After that, we set up a trap - in case you hit `CTRL - C`, both programs will get killed.
The `wait` line will block until both the flask and npm process has finished - so you can easily terminate both with `CTRL-C`.